# Unicity of $x^2f''+xf'-n^2f=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove a solution  to $r^2f''+rf'-n^2f=0$ in $x>0$ is of the form $f(r)=ar^n+br^{-n}$.

Clearly $f(r)=ar^n+br^{-n}$ satisfies $r^2f''+rf'-n^2f=0$ for $r>0$. Suppouse by way of contradiction $g$ also satisfies this equation. We have:

$$f(1)=a+b \quad \quad f(x_o)=ax_o^n+b x_o^{-n}$$

Because $\det \begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\ x_o^n & x_o^{-n}\end{bmatrix}=0\Leftrightarrow x_o^{2n}=1$, if we take $x_o>1$ or $0<x_o<1$ we can make $f$ coincide with $g$ on $1$ and $x_o$ choosing $a$ and $b$ appropriatley. Let us consider $h=f-g$. This is also a solution which is zero on $1$ and $x_o$. If we have

$$E=h^2$$

I want to prove $E$ is constant and hence equal to zero at all points, but this doesn't seem to do the trick...

Comment: The second plus should be a minus? Solutions of boundary-value problems need not be unique, but for linear DE there is something like the Fredholm alternative.

Comment: Sorry, which second plus?

Comment: Yes! That was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably easier to consider $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ instead of $f(1)$ and $f(x_0)$ with $x_0 \neq 1$. Indeed, this is a second order ODE thus for any solutions $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$, if $f(1) = g(1)$ and $f'(1) = g'(1)$, then $f = g$ everywhere (the same argument works with any $x_0 > 0$ instead of $1$ by the way).

You have $f(1) = a + b$ and $f'(1) = na - nb$. If $n \neq 0$, then $\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ n & -n \end{pmatrix} = -2n \neq 0$ so we can always find $a$ and $b$ such that $f(1) = g(1)$ and $f'(1) = g'(1)$, which proves that $f = g$.

If $n = 0$, however, the equation becomes $r^2f'' + rf' = 0$, which admits the non-constant solution $f(r) = \ln(r)$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$, which has not the form $ar^0 + br^{-0} = a + b = $ constant.

you could also argue that the set of solution is a real vector space of dimension $2$ because the equation is an order $2$ ODE and the family $(r \mapsto r^n,r \mapsto r^{-n})$ is free if and only if $n \neq 0$. It means there is an other solution than the ones of the form $r \mapsto ar^n + br^{-n}$ if and only if $n = 0$.

Comment: Could you prove if $f$ and $g$ coincide in the point and in their derivative $f=g$?

Comment: @Kadmos : This is just general theory of linear DE, wherever the coefficients are continuous, and the leading one non-zero, the first-order system of the DE is locally Lipschitz and you get existence (on any closed sub-interval) and uniqueness.